# Why the hamburger menu does not display correctly in Firefox and does not open on one page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few pages. On all menu pages the hamburger works correctly, except for the main page. On the main page, the hamburger menu does not open, although javascript is connected everywhere, I checked. Also, in the browser Firefox, the last  is much lower than it should, although in other browsers everything is displayed correctly. What could be the mistake?

```js
if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
  var click = 'touchstart';
} else {
  var click = 'click';
}


$('div.burger').on(click, function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
    openMenu();
  } else {
    closeMenu();
  }
});

$('div.menu ul li a').on(click, function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  closeMenu();
});


function openMenu() {
  (document.getElementById("see").setAttribute("style", "display: block; z-index: 30;"));

  $('div.burger').addClass('open');
  $('div.x, div.z').addClass('collapse');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div.y').hide();
    $('div.x').addClass('rotate30');
    $('div.z').addClass('rotate150');
  }, 70);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div.x').addClass('rotate45');
    $('div.z').addClass('rotate135');
  }, 120);
}

function closeMenu() {

  $('.menu li').removeClass('animate');
  (document.getElementById("see").setAttribute("style", "display: none; z-index: 20;"));
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div.burger').removeClass('open');
    $('div.x').removeClass('rotate45').addClass('rotate30');
    $('div.z').removeClass('rotate135').addClass('rotate150');
    $('div.menu-bg').removeClass('animate');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div.x').removeClass('rotate30');
      $('div.z').removeClass('rotate150');
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('div.y').show();
      $('div.x, div.z').removeClass('collapse');
    }, 70);
  }, 100);

}
```

```css
.container_header {
  background: url(../img/img1.jpg) top center no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 960px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.container-header a {
  float: left;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.firstname {
  font-size: 7.5rem;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 7%;
  margin-left: 52%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.firstname p {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav {
  display: block;
}

.nav a {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: -278px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 310px;
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 27%;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 381px) {
  .parallax {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
    background-image: url(../img/Фон.png);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
  }
  div.burger {
    height: 30px;
    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    left: 21px;
    z-index: 30;
  }
  div.x,
  div.y,
  div.z {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  }
  div.x,
  div.y,
  div.z {
    height: 3px;
    width: 26px;
  }
  div.y {
    top: 18px;
  }
  div.z {
    top: 37px;
  }
  div.collapse {
    top: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 70ms ease-out;
    transition: all 70ms ease-out;
  }
  div.rotate30 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
    transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  }
  div.rotate150 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
    transform: rotate(150deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 50ms ease-out;
    transition: all 50ms ease-out;
  }
  div.rotate45 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
    transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  }
  div.rotate135 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
    transition: all 100ms ease-out;
  }
  div.menu-bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
    -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
    transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.995, 0.990, 1.000);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="container_header">
  <nav class="nav" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-bg"></div>
    <ul class="menu" id="see">
      <li class="home"><a class="icon home_bar" href="index.html"><span>Text</span></a></li>
      <li class="gallery"><a class="icon gallery_bar" href="pages/gallery.html"><span>Text</span></a></li>
      <li class="ut"><a class="icon ut_bar" href="pages/usefulTips.html"><span>Text</span></a></li>
      <li class="contact"><a class="icon contact_bar" href="pages/contacts.html"><span>Text</span></a></li>
      <li class="journal"><a class="icon journal_bar" href="#"><span>Text</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="x"></div>
      <div class="y"></div>
      <div class="z"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="firstname">
    <h1 class="name-main">Text
      <p>Text</p>
    </h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Different browsers have different standard "settings" on margins and paddings of html elements. It could be that because of this your menu is not displayed correctly

Comment: As @KevinTinnemans said - I would suggest removing the `margin: auto` from your `x,y,z` classes. You don't need it since you are absolutely positioning elements. You can then just use the `top` value to move them. That should remain consistent across all browsers.

Comment: At the beginning of my code I have css reset by Eric Mayer

Comment: @Alexandra that doesn't matter, since you are adding `margin: auto` to the `x,y,z` elements in your code - which you do not need.

Comment: Thank you, it helped, now everything <span> in place. But what about the fact that menu does not open on this page when clicked? Then how does everything work correctly on other pages?

Comment: Have you checked the console? If it’s not opening on one page only, it sounds to me like your jQuery isn’t working. Check the console to see if you’ve any errors - that would stop the rest of the jQuery from running.

Comment: The menu opens on the other four pages, but not on the main page. So I posted the code this page so someone would tell me where the error might be